# Out of order UV pipelines

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, pipeline, microprocessors

Here is an example of out of order pipeline from "The Intel Microprocessor Family" by James Antonakos.

Consider this sequence of instructions. The number of clock cycles assigned to each instruction is fabricated for this example.

```
1: MOV AL, 2       ; 1 cycle
2: MOV DL, [SI]    ; 3 cycles
3: MUL DL          ; 2 cycles
4: INC SI          ; 1 cycle
5: SUB BX, 4       ; 1 cycle
6: ADD AX, BX      ; 1 cycle
7: MOV CX, 2000    ; 1 cycle
```

Scheduling instructions **in order** between two pipelines: (I know the basic concept of this.)

```
Clock Cycle     Pipeline # 1       Pipeline # 2

1                MOV AL, 5         MOV DL, [SI]
2                idle              busy
3                idle              busy
4                MUL DL            INC SI
5                busy              SUB BX, 4
6                ADD AX, BX        MOV CX, 2000
```

Scheduling instructions **out of order** between two pipelines:

```
Clock Cycle     Pipeline # 1       Pipeline # 2

1                MOV AL, 5         MOV DL, [SI]
2                INC SI            SUB BX, 4
3                MOV CX, 2000      busy
4                MUL DL            idle
5                ADD AX, BX        idle
```

Can someone explain to me how out of order pipeline is done? Thank you!

Comment: there's a unit which analyzes the upcoming code, and figures out depedencies between the individual instructions. if (say) a memory load comes in that'd stall the pipe for a while, the cpu will try to schedule some other independent instructions before/after the load operation, so they can execute while the load is waiting for the memory system to respond. same instructions being operated, but running in less cycles because you're wasting cycles on waiting for other things.

Comment: I see. Another question. When we're asked to draw the UV pipeline, NOP is used as a placeholder. What's the difference between busy and idle in pipelining?

Comment: Busy means the pipeline is still finishing up an instruction (since some instructions take more than 1 cycle). Idle means the pipeline is doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out of order engine will simply take any ready (ones that aren't waiting on any dependencies) opcodes (instructions that have been broken down into multiple parts) and schedule them for execution. How far it looks ahead depends on how many instructions have been fetched and decoded by the front end.

In your out of order example, you won't be able to execute the "INC SI" until after the "MOV DL, [SI]" has ready SI and gone through AGEN (address generation) to load from. The "SUB BX, 4", however, has no dependencies and is ready to get scheduled to execute whenever the HW sees it, etc..